# I have 2 identical HID USB devices, each one has it's own control program, how can each program know which HID device is theres?

Tags: winapi, operating-system, usb

Is there a way to assign one HID device to a program and then another identical HID device to another program without each of them grabbing randomly the first HID device they enumerate? I'd need some kind of unique identifier. Is there such thing? On windows xp/vista/7.

Answer (score 0):

The port is your default enumeration value. Configure your code to allow explicit specification of the port.

Depending on a uuid of a device is probably not going to give you the results you expect in the long run.